# mysql query not inserting string into table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been able to manually insert values in my table using phpmyadmin, and even if i end up using the same php code i get from php my admin to call the query it STILL won't add the value to the table.   here is the code:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_select_db('sc2broating1', $link);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `sc2broad_tesing1`.`Persons` (`re`) VALUES (\'hello11\')";

mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't escape value.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `sc2broad_tesing1`.`Persons` (`re`) VALUES ('hello11')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider using bound parameters, as seen in [mysqli::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), if [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is an option.